# Shared resource ownage using std::weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

I'm wondering about how to (using C++11 and hopefully with backwards (boost or TR1) compatible smart pointer types) achieve:

One class instance (`ModelController`) owns a resource (`InputConsumer`), while another component (`InputSender`, which in this case is a singleton) has access to it.

The model is `InputSender` holds a list of references to `InputConsumers`, of which there will be many.

`ModelController` may have none, one, or many `InputConsumers`, and there may be many `ModelController`s. The `InputSender` is NOT aware.

Here's what would be nice: A way for `InputSender` to track the `InputConsumers` assigned to it, in such a way that it can find out for itself whether the individual `InputConsumers` are valid or not.

It seems to me that `weak_ptr` is perfect for this purpose as their use requires checking this condition.

If `InputSender` stops tracking any of its `weak_ptr` refs, nothing bad happens, the corresponding `InputConsumer`s will just experience radio silence.

If a `ModelController` is deleted, or if a `ModelController` deletes some of its `InputConsumer`s, any `InputSender`s that have registered with them will recognize at the next time they try to access them that they no longer exist, and can clean up, without the need to send a message or do anything.

So the question is, is this an appropriate situation for using `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`? I wonder if `shared_ptr` is completely appropriate because the `InputConsumer`s are conceptually *owned* by their `ModelController`s, so they should be member variables. I dunno how much sense it makes for `ModelController` to only manage them via `shared_ptr`. I can't tell if `unique_ptr` works together with `weak_ptr`. Am I supposed to just manage the `shared_ptr`s in `ModelController`'s ctor/dtor?

There may also be a well-known (not to me!) design pattern that this falls into, so if anyone knows of such a thing please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a lot of expertise in shared pointers, but yes, this seems a very appropriate use of `weak_ptr`.

In this case, you are just annoyed that:

1. You would like to use `InputConsumer`s directly as members of `ModelController`s, since its a trivial ownership relation.
2. You are forced to use a `shared_ptr` to make it work with a `weak_ptr`.

I think this is solved by using a `shared_ptr` as an *alias* of a member object. According to [C++.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/):

> Additionally, shared_ptr objects can share ownership over a pointer
>   while at the same time pointing to another object. This ability is
>   known as aliasing (see constructors), and is commonly used to point to
>   member objects while owning the object they belong to.

I never did it myself, but this seems adapted to your situation:

- Have `InputConsumer`s members of `ModelController`s
- Have an alias `shared_ptr` for each of them
- Reference them in `InputSender` using `weak_ptr`s

**EDIT**

Here is a complete minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// A class to try our smart pointers on
struct Foo 
{
    Foo() { cout << "constructing Foo\n"; }
    ~Foo() { cout << "destructing Foo\n"; }
};

// A class that owns some Foo as members
struct Owner
{
    // The actual members
    Foo foo1;
    Foo foo2;

    // A fake shared pointer whose purpose is:
    //   1) to be of type shared_ptr<>
    //   2) to have the same lifetime as foo1 and foo2
    shared_ptr<Owner> self;

    // A fake deleter that actually deletes nothing 
    struct Deleter
    {
        void operator() (Owner *) { cout << "pretend to delete Owner\n"; }
    };

    Owner() : self(this, Deleter()) { cout << "constructing Owner\n"; }
    ~Owner()                        { cout << "destructing Owner\n"; }
};

// A class that holds a reference to a Foo
struct Observer
{
    // A reference to a Foo, as a weak pointer
    weak_ptr<Foo> foo_ptr;

    Observer(const shared_ptr<Foo> & foo_ptr) : foo_ptr(foo_ptr)
    {
        cout << "constructing Observer\n";
    }
    ~Observer() { cout << "destructing Observer\n"; }

    void check()
    {
        if(foo_ptr.expired())
            cout << "foo expired\n";
        else
            cout << "foo still exists\n";
    }   
};  

int main()
{
    // Create Owner, and hence foo1 and foo2
    Owner * owner = new Owner;

    // Create an observer, passing an alias of &(owner->foo1) to ctor
    Observer observer(shared_ptr<Foo>(owner->self, &(owner->foo1)));

    // Try to access owner->foo1 from observer
    observer.check();
    delete owner;
    observer.check();

    return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
constructing Foo
constructing Foo
constructing Owner
constructing Observer
foo still exists
destructing Owner
pretend to delete Owner
destructing Foo
destructing Foo
foo expired
destructing Observer
```

The tricky part is to be able to create a `weak_ptr` to `owner->foo1` (would be the same for `foo2`). To do that, we first need a `shared_ptr` that is an alias of `owner->foo1`. This can only be done by:

```
shared_ptr<Foo> alias(other_shared_ptr, &(owner->foo1));
```

where `other_shared_ptr` is a `shared_ptr<T>` whose lifetime is at least as long as the one of `owner->foo1`. To achieve this, using a `shared_ptr<T>` which is also a member of `owner` is a good idea, since it ensures the lifetime would be the same. Finally, we need a valid non-null pointer to give to it, and since we don't want to create anything on the heap, we must use an existing object. `this` is a good candidate, since we know it is valid and get destroyed only after its members are destroyed. Hence our `other_shared_ptr` is for instance:

```
shared_ptr<Owner> self(this);
```

However, this means that when `self` gets out of scope, i.e. during the destruction of `owner`, it will call `delete this`. We do *not* want this deletion to occur, otherwise `this` would be deleted twice (which is undefined behaviour, in practice a segfault). Hence we also provide to the constructor of `self` a Deleter that actually doesn't delete anything.

The rest of the code should be self-explanatory with the comments.

Comment: This sounds really cool, but it isn't immediately clear to me how to go about aliasing them! Could you post a small example? Thanks!

Comment: @StevenLu I never used aliases before so I had to learn the details, and it's actually trickier that I expected. Anyway, it was worth the effort, now I understand them quite well and have a working example that I'm sharing with you (see edit). The alternative is not to use these aliases, and have directly `shared_ptr<Foo> foo1_ptr` members of `Owner`, initialized with `Owner() : foo1_ptr(new Foo) {}`, and then directly use `Observer observer(owner->foo1_ptr)`, but this create data on the heap that you may want to avoid.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to avoid the slightly unseemly fake deleter. What sort of havoc is wreaked by ignoring the deleter? I guess it will double-free the class instance and crash us, since shared_ptr is meant to be used for newly allocated items. :( Although, maybe I can hide away the trickiness by implementing it in the general case as a base class, or perhaps even better a template.

Comment: @StevenLu Yes, if you don't provide this dummy Deleter, `owner` gets deleted twice, which results in a segfault (I did try). This "hack" seems the only possible solution that doesn't involves allocating something on the heap. Indeed, if nothing is on the heap, then it means no `new` has been called, hence no `delete` should be called either. But you do need a `shared_ptr` to a non-null address (to be able to use `weak_ptr`), and it would call delete by default, then segfault. :-/ Thx for the comment on my website :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just one more complete working snippet, showing std::weak_ptr dynamics, maybe can help a little bit more. (I particulary liked this expired() semantics);

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<string>

class MessageProcessor{                
};

class Message{
public:

        Message(std::shared_ptr<MessageProcessor>  _msg_proc, int _id){
                proc_weak = std::weak_ptr<MessageProcessor>(_msg_proc);
                proc_shared = _msg_proc;
                id = _id;
        }

        std::weak_ptr<MessageProcessor> proc_weak;
        std::shared_ptr<MessageProcessor> proc_shared;        
        int id;
};

int main(){

        std::shared_ptr<MessageProcessor> proc(new MessageProcessor());

        Message msg(proc,1);

        // Here we have proc with 2 shared_ptr refs: 'proc' and 'msg.proc_shared'
        // As expected 'msg.proc_weak is not expired'
        if( !msg.proc_weak.expired() )
                std::cout << "1) proc_weak is not EXPIRED. proc.use_count() == " << proc.use_count() << std::endl;        

        // make one of shared_ptr ref, point to other place
        msg.proc_shared = std::shared_ptr<MessageProcessor>();        

        // there is still the 'proc' reference        
        if( !msg.proc_weak.expired() )
                std::cout << "2) proc_weak is not EXPIRED (yet). proc.use_count() == " << proc.use_count() << std::endl;

        // 'erase' the last reference
        proc = std::shared_ptr<MessageProcessor>(); 

        // Finally... There is no more refs in shared_pointer!
        if( msg.proc_weak.expired() )
                std::cout << "3) proc_weak has EXPIRED. proc.use_count() == " << proc.use_count() << std::endl;

        return 0; 
}
```